# Nueva API de AFIP en PHP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

como implementar el nuevo servicio **SOAP** de la **API** de **AFIP** en `PHP`?

Está pregunta nace ya que se que a muchos les ha ocurrido lo mismo y espero que logremos llegar a una solución.

Hasta hace nada mas que una semana venia utilizando la api rest de **AFIP** la cual consultaba pasandole un parametro `cuit` por medio de la `url` y recibia un `Json` de los datos.

Sin embargo, por alguna razón decidieron darla de baja, dejando todo mi sistema obsoleto. Y ademas la inexistente documentacion que encontré se encuentra en python

Ahora debo ingeniarmelas para hacer un refactor de mi app actualizando el metodo con el que obtengo los datos y usando la nueva version de la `API` en `SOAP`

API REST:

"https://soa.afip.gov.ar/sr-padron/v2/persona/30500010912"

API SOAP:

"https://awshomo.afip.gov.ar/sr-padron/webservices/personaServiceA10"

Lamentablemente mi conocimiento del `WS` **SOAP** es casi nulo. Por eso estoy preguntando por este medio.

Segun este manual (a mi parecer inentendible):

"https://www.afip.gob.ar/ws/ws_sr_padron_a10/manual_ws_sr_padron_a10_v1.1.pdf"

Debo usar el metodo `getPersona()`

Aqui el codigo de ejemplo que me brinda la pagina oficial:

```
!/usr/bin/php
<?php
# Author: Gerardo Fisanotti - DvSHyS/DiOPIN/AFIP - 13-apr-07
# Function: Get an authorization ticket (TA) from AFIP WSAA
# Input:
#        WSDL, CERT, PRIVATEKEY, PASSPHRASE, SERVICE, URL
#        Check below for its definitions
# Output:
#        TA.xml: the authorization ticket as granted by WSAA.
#==============================================================================
define ("WSDL", "wsaa.wsdl");     # The WSDL corresponding to WSAA
define ("CERT", "ghf.crt");       # The X.509 certificate in PEM format
define ("PRIVATEKEY", "ghf.key"); # The private key correspoding to CERT (PEM)
define ("PASSPHRASE", "xxxxx"); # The passphrase (if any) to sign
define ("PROXY_HOST", "10.20.152.112"); # Proxy IP, to reach the Internet
define ("PROXY_PORT", "80");            # Proxy TCP port
define ("URL", "https://wsaahomo.afip.gov.ar/ws/services/LoginCms");
#define ("URL", "https://wsaa.afip.gov.ar/ws/services/LoginCms");
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# You shouldn't have to change anything below this line!!!
#==============================================================================
function CreateTRA($SERVICE)
{
  $TRA = new SimpleXMLElement(
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' .
    '<loginTicketRequest version="1.0">'.
    '</loginTicketRequest>');
  $TRA->addChild('header');
  $TRA->header->addChild('uniqueId',date('U'));
  $TRA->header->addChild('generationTime',date('c',date('U')-60));
  $TRA->header->addChild('expirationTime',date('c',date('U')+60));
  $TRA->addChild('service',$SERVICE);
  $TRA->asXML('TRA.xml');
}
#==============================================================================
# This functions makes the PKCS#7 signature using TRA as input file, CERT and
# PRIVATEKEY to sign. Generates an intermediate file and finally trims the 
# MIME heading leaving the final CMS required by WSAA.
function SignTRA()
{
  $STATUS=openssl_pkcs7_sign("TRA.xml", "TRA.tmp", "file://".CERT,
    array("file://".PRIVATEKEY, PASSPHRASE),
    array(),
    !PKCS7_DETACHED
    );
  if (!$STATUS) {exit("ERROR generating PKCS#7 signature\n");}
  $inf=fopen("TRA.tmp", "r");
  $i=0;
  $CMS="";
  while (!feof($inf)) 
    { 
      $buffer=fgets($inf);
      if ( $i++ >= 4 ) {$CMS.=$buffer;}
    }
  fclose($inf);
#  unlink("TRA.xml");
  unlink("TRA.tmp");
  return $CMS;
}
#==============================================================================
function CallWSAA($CMS)
{
  $client=new SoapClient(WSDL, array(
          'proxy_host'     => PROXY_HOST,
          'proxy_port'     => PROXY_PORT,
          'soap_version'   => SOAP_1_2,
          'location'       => URL,
          'trace'          => 1,
          'exceptions'     => 0
          )); 
  $results=$client->loginCms(array('in0'=>$CMS));
  file_put_contents("request-loginCms.xml",$client->__getLastRequest());
  file_put_contents("response-loginCms.xml",$client->__getLastResponse());
  if (is_soap_fault($results)) 
    {exit("SOAP Fault: ".$results->faultcode."\n".$results->faultstring."\n");}
  return $results->loginCmsReturn;
}
#==============================================================================
function ShowUsage($MyPath)
{
  printf("Uso  : %s Arg#1 Arg#2\n", $MyPath);
  printf("donde: Arg#1 debe ser el service name del WS de negocio.\n");
  printf("  Ej.: %s wsfe\n", $MyPath);
}
#==============================================================================
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
if (!file_exists(CERT)) {exit("Failed to open ".CERT."\n");}
if (!file_exists(PRIVATEKEY)) {exit("Failed to open ".PRIVATEKEY."\n");}
if (!file_exists(WSDL)) {exit("Failed to open ".WSDL."\n");}
if ( $argc < 2 ) {ShowUsage($argv[0]); exit();}
$SERVICE=$argv[1];
CreateTRA($SERVICE);
$CMS=SignTRA();
$TA=CallWSAA($CMS);
if (!file_put_contents("TA.xml", $TA)) {exit();}
?>
```

Comment: Porque decis que el ejemplo esta en python. Eso no es PHP?

Comment: No. quise decir, que hay algunos proyectos o info hecha en python. Este es el codigo base para obtener un Ticket de acceso. simplemente para eso es este codigo en pp que brinda la pagina oficial.

Comment: Pero mas alla de la implementacion, es un servicio SOAP comun.. No tiene nada raro, ni requiere un acceso distinto. Tu problema es que no sabes SOAP? u otra cosa?

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema que vos, un Sistema que desarrollo utilizaba la API **Rest** y ahora tendría que usar **SOAP**. Encontré esto que quizás puede servirte, yo hice algunas pruebas y algunos datos los trae bien y otros no. Quizás te sirva de algo
(reemplaza *:dni* por el DNI de la persona) [`https://www.sistemasagiles.com.ar/padron/consulta/persona/:dni/`](http://%60https://www.sistemasagiles.com.ar/padron/consulta/persona/:dni/%60) Chequea tambien [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pyafipws/S65ziE5-_5k/Mn16nYJfBAAJ](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pyafipws/S65ziE5-_5k/Mn16nYJfBA

Answer (score 2):

`getPersona()`, ese método no existe, no se entiendo bien que estás consultando, de ese archivo tenes que *setear*

```
define ("CERT", "ghf.crt");       # The X.509 certificate in PEM format
define ("PRIVATEKEY", "ghf.key"); # The private key correspoding to CERT (PEM)
```

y si el ambiente con el que queres interactuar el HML o Prod

```
define ("URL", "https://wsaahomo.afip.gov.ar/ws/services/LoginCms");
define ("URL", "https://wsaa.afip.gov.ar/ws/services/LoginCms");
```

nada mas.
en el `response` vas a tener el `token` y `sign` para operar

Answer (score 0):

Aqui hay un SDK en php que funciona https://github.com/AfipSDK/afip.php/tree/master/src/Class

te puede servir como punta pie para realizar el tuyo.